# How to generate the brackets in row name?

Tags: r

How to generate the brackets  in  row name ?

```
data.frame("gender"=c("man","woman"),"number(live in school)"=c(2340,1890))

  gender number.live.in.school.
1    man                   2340
2  woman                   1890
```

What i want to get the format output is :

```
  gender   number(live in school)
1    man                   2340
2  woman                   1890
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the argument `check.names = FALSE`:

```
data.frame("gender" = c("man","woman"), "number(live in school)" = c(2340,1890), 
           check.names = FALSE)

#   gender number(live in school)
# 1    man                   2340
# 2  woman                   1890
```